# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') in React - Comment Section

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a comment section. I am reading the data that is being saved in a database. However when reading the comments from an array of comments its giving issue on this line

```
 const message_list =response.data.results.data.message.map((value) => (value));
```

Ive taken the code from this
https://riyanegi.github.io/react-comments-documentation/

```
axios.get(  process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL +"product/" + this.product_id +"/idea/"+ this.idea_id +"/comment",{ 
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer "+ user_access_token,
    }})
.then(response => {
  const message_list =response.data.results.data.message.map((value) => (value));
  this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...message_list] });
   });
```

And then I am rendering:

```
render() {
    return <CommentSection
          currentUser={{
            currentUserId: this.currentUser.user,
            currentUserImg:
              'https://ui-avatars.com/api/name='+this.currentUser.name+  '&background=random',
            currentUserFullName:  this.currentUser.name
          }}
          commentData={this.state.data}
          onSubmitAction={(data) => this.onSubmitAction(data)}
          onEditAction={(data) => this.onEditAction(data)}
          onDeleteAction={(data) => this.onDeleteAction(data)}
          customNoComment={() => this.customNoComment()}
          onReplyAction = {(data)=>this.onReplyAction(data)}
        />
  }
```

Comment: Without knowing what your API returns, my first suggestion would be `console.log(response.data)` and troubleshoot from there

Comment: 0
: 
commentId
: 
5006
ideaId
: 
1
parentOfEditedCommentId
: 
0
repliedToComment
: 
0
text
: 
"New commentu"
userId
: 
5021
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
{commentId: 5007, parentOfEditedCommentId: 0, userId: 5021, repliedToComment: 0, ideaId: 1, …}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `console.log` you provided, it appears that `response.data.results.data` may need to be just `response.data`. You can confirm this by checking the console output to ensure that `message` is a property on it, and `results` isn't.

In any case, if you examine the object in your console to find the message array that you're trying to map, you should be able to find your `message` array nested somewhere in there.